# Call functions in order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, synchronization

Hello i am always confused about sync async functions in javascript. I want to use 2 useState functions but i want it run them in order. The code is just an example. How i can run them in sync ?

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
const [page, page] = useState(0) 

setNumber(prev => prev++)  //first 
setpage(number)           // start when setNumber function is finished

// current output: number=1, page=0 -- number=2, page=1 -- number=3, page=2
// what i want:    number=1, page=1 -- number=2, page=2 -- number=3, page=3
```

Comment: That's exactly what these functions currently do.  What "output" are you referring to?  This code produces no output.

Comment: `await` will wait for Promises to resolve. If the 2 functions are synchronous, they will automatically run in order.

Comment: I *suspect* you're expecting the `number` state value to have been updated immediately.  This expectation is incorrect.  State updates are batched for performance.  Fortunately you already have the value you need: `setPage(number + 1)`  Though if `page` and `number` are always maintained in lockstep with one another, why are both needed in the first place?

Comment: You can't use the updated state value in the same render cycle. Either put the `setPage` call in a useEffect dependent on `number` or store the number in a temp variable, increment it, and call both setState calls with the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a new variable to do this:

```
const newValue = number + 1;
setNumber(newValue);
setpage(newValue);
```

Or using `useEffect`, it will call when `setNumber` finish and component re-render

```
useEffect(() => {
  setpage(number);
}, number);
```